# Concordância em número com o verbo ser: «o pomar é cinco árvores» ou «o pomar são cinco árvores»?

Tags: concordância-verbal

Encontrei [este poema do Pessoa](http://arquivopessoa.net/textos/1488) já não sei onde:

> Sou um guardador de rebanhos.
> O rebanho é os meus pensamentos
> E os meus pensamentos são todos sensações.
> [...]

Se o Pessoa o escreveu é porque deve estar bem, mas ***o rebanho é os meus pensamentos*** ficou-me a tilintar na cabeça. Esperaria ***o rebanho são os meus pensamentos***. Então como é quando temos um nome singular ligado pelo verbo ser a um nome plural? Outro exemplo:

> Ele disse que a casa tinha pomar?! Sim, sim
>
> (a) *o pomar **são** estas cinco árvores* ou (b) *o pomar **é** estas cinco árvores*?

Aqui *são* soa-me definitivamente melhor que *é*. No exemplo seguinte continuo a preferir *são*, mas não tão definitivamente:

> (c) *A minha preocupação **são** os filhos* ou (d) *a minha preocupação **é** os filhos*?

E se começarmos com o nome plural:

> (e) *Estas cinco árvores **são** o pomar* ou (f) *estas cinco árvores **é** o pomar*
>
> (g) *Os filhos **são** a minha preocupação* ou (h) *Os filhos **é** a minha preocupação*

As duas formas estão corretas? As gramáticas preferem alguma delas? Depende de ser *nome singular [ser] nome plural* ou o inverso? A minha maior recetividade ao *é* em (d) do que em (b) será uma idiossincrasia minha, ou há uma tendência geral para uma maior preferência ou aceitação do singular em certos contextos?

Comment: Se for *são* no (a) ou (c), o sujeito é o 1º nome singular, ou o 2º nome plural? Se é o singular, fica singular ou "muda" para plural?

Comment: @DanGetz Não sei dizer. Na minha cabeça o primeiro nome é sujeito: estou a dizer o que o pomar é.

Comment: Se o português seguir as mesma gramática das outras línguas ibéricas (e imagino que sim a segue nisto), ambas estão corretas, com preferência geral por parte dos falantes pela flexão plural, mas quando a parte plural tem sentido coletivo ou unitário, aparece con mais frequência a forma singular.  Desafortunadamente não tenho nenhuma gramática portuguesa comigo para verificar.

Comment: Então e que tal: _Quais pomares? Esta árvore é/são os pomares. Não resta mais nada._ Qual é que preferirias?

Comment: O que [esta tese diz](https://repositorio-aberto.up.pt/bitstream/10216/13058/2/4907TM01PMARIACARMOOLIVEIRA000069363.pdf), se estou a ler corretamente, é que a concordância de copulativas invertidas (em que é o predicado da oração pequena que é elevado) se faz à direita em português (e italiano), ao contrário do inglês (e presumivelmente à esqda c.c.). Essa ideia deve poder ser testada arranjando uma copulativa em que a oração pequena tem sujeito singular e predicado plural, usando lá os testes que ela tira de Heycock. Hei de ver se isso leva a algum lado.

Comment: @Artefacto *Esta árvore é os pomares*; mas *os pomares são esta árvore*. Hã!? Terá que ver com a semântica: *pomar* pode ser visto como uma pluralidade, enquanto *árvore* não?

Comment: @Artefacto Em *esta árvore é os pomares* continua para mim a haver uma certa dissonância; mas talvez nós a aceitemos para reforçar a ideia que a informação dada, haver pomares, estava errada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comecemos pelo que diz Evanildo Bechara na sua *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa* (pág. 673 da versão eletrónica da 37.ª ed., citações omitidas):

> Nas orações ditas equativas em que com ser se exprime a definição
> ou a identidade, o verbo, posto entre dois substantivos de números diferentes, concorda em geral com aquele que estiver no plural. Às vezes, um
> dos termos é um pronome:
>
> > A pátria não *é* ninguém: *são* todos.
>
> Mas:
>
> > Justiça é tudo, justiça *é as virtudes todas*.

Verdade, mas isto é apenas uma constatação, não uma explicação científica. As questões interessante são explicar essa concordância e, de forma relacionada, que factores favorecem o singular ou o plural. Sobre as frases ditas *identificacionais* ou *equativas*, podemos ver o capítulo 13 na  *Gramática da Língua Portuguesa* (Lisboa: Caminho, 6.ª ed., 2003), de Inês Duarte, e a tese de mestrado de [Maria Oliveira (2001)](https://repositorio-aberto.up.pt/bitstream/10216/13058/2/4907TM01PMARIACARMOOLIVEIRA000069363.pdf). Ambas se baseiam no livro de Andrea Moro ([*The Raising of Predicates*](http://www.worldcat.org/title/raising-of-predicates-predicative-noun-phrases-and-the-theory-of-clause-structure/oclc/34517408&referer=brief_results). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1997); Maria Oliveira também no trabalho de Caroline Heycock ([*The Internal Structure of Small Clauses: New Evidence for Inversion*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.3446&rep=rep1&type=pdf), em *Proceedings of NELS 25*, 1994, pp. 223-238).

Nestes trabalhos, o tratamento das frases identificacionais é semelhante àquele das frases atributivas como *A Maria é simpática* na medida em que todas contêm um domínio de predicação não frásico, **uma oração pequena**, a qual tem uma posição de sujeito e uma de predicado.

A maioria das frases ditas *identificacionais* não apresenta uma estrutura simétrica, resultado de uma posição fixa dos dois constituintes da oração pequena. Os autores que referi distinguem uma **frases copulativas canónicas**, em que o sujeito da oração pequena se encontra em posição pré-verbal, das **frases copulativas invertidas**, em que este está em posição pós-verbal.

Sobre a estrutura de cada um dos tipos de frases, veja-se Duarte (2003, pág. 545) e Oliveira (2001, pág. 120) para as invertidas e Duarte (2003, pág. 543) para as canónicas (e atributivas). As propostas parecem ter algumas diferenças, mas no que toca à concordância vão na mesma linha.

Oliveira (2001) afirma que «em português a concordância das das frases copulativas invertidas é feita à direita». Dá estes exemplos:

> - O João e a Maria **foram** a causa do motim.
> - A causa do motim **foram** o João e a Maria.
> - *A causa do motim **foi** o João e a Maria.

Da mesma forma, Duarte (2003) diz:

> As frases copulativas canónicas e invertidas apresentam padrões de concordância sujeito-verbo particularmente interessantes. Assim, a concordância de pessoa e número é sempre determinada pelo constituinte que ocupa a posição de sujeito da oração pequena, como se pode observar nos exemplos (29):
>
> > (29) (a) [Tu]<sub>i</sub> és [<sub>OPeq</sub> [v]<sub>i</sub> o professor].
> > (b) [O professor]<sub>j</sub> és [tu]<sub>i</sub> [<sub>OPeq</sub> [v]<sub>i</sub> [v]<sub>j</sub> ].

O problema é que nem sempre é fácil determinar qual é o sujeito. Nem sempre é claro qual é o constituinte com maior valor referencial. Das duas fontes, podemos retirar os seguintes testes:

1. Só nas canónicas o foco pode ocorrer em ambos os elementos; nas invertidas, o foco só pode ocorrer no elemento pós-cópula.
2. Não é possível clivar o SN em posição pré-verbal nas frases invertidas. Oliveira (2001) diz ser um teste em relação ao qual mais pares se comportam de igual forma. No entanto, eu tenho bastante dificuldade em aceitar as frases (191b) e (192b) (pág. 116).
3. Numa frase *cópula SX SX*, a ordem dos constituintes tem de ser a canónica (sujeito primeiro).
4. Redobro do sujeito só é viável quando o pronome retoma o sujeito da oração pequena.
5. Só o predicado pode ser substituído pelo clítico invariável *o*.

Vejamos então a frase original:

> O pomar são estas cinco árvores. ([estas cinco árvores] [o pomar])

1. O pomar são estas cinco árvores ou aquelas duas árvores?
   O pomar são ESTAS CINCO ÁRVORES. (I)
   ESTAS CINCO ÁRVORES são o pomar. (C)

   Estas cinco árvores são o pomar ou as árvores para vender?
   *O POMAR são estas cinco árvores. (I)
   Estas cinco árvores são O POMAR.  (C)
2. *É o pomar que é estas cinco árvores. (I)
   São estas cinco árvores que são o pomar. (C)
3. *É o pomar estas cinco árvores. (I)
   São estas cinco árvores o pomar. (C)
4. *O pomar, ele são/é estas cinco árvores. (I)
   Estas cinco árvores, elas são o pomar. (C)
5. *Estas cinco árvores, o pomar são-no/é-o. (I)
   O pomar, estas cinco árvores são-no. / Estas cinco árvores são o pomar, e aqueloutras também o são. (C)

O teu outro exemplo:

> A minha preocupação são os filhos. ([os filhos] [a minha preocupação])

1. Os filhos são a tua preocupação ou o teu distraimento?
   *A MINHA PREOCUPAÇÃO são os filhos. (I)
   Os filhos são A MINHA PREOCUPAÇÃO.  (C)

Podemos agora tentar ver o comportamento com a tua frase original, mas alterando os números de cada um dos sintagmas nominais. Não me concentrarei no uso de *é* vs. *são*; marco como aceitável se pelo menos uma das formas é aceitável.

> Quais pomares? Esta árvore é/são os pomares. ([esta árvore] [os pomares]) (?)

1. Esta árvore é os pomares ou a árvore do vizinho?
   Esta árvore é/são OS POMARES. (C)
   *OS POMARES é/são esta árvore. (I)

   Os pomares são esta árvore ou as árvores no fundo da rua?
   ESTA ÁRVORE é/são os pomares. (C)
   Os pomares é/são ESTA ÁRVORE. (I)
2. É esta árvore que é/são os pomares. (C)
   *É/São os pomares que é/são esta árvore. (I)
3. É esta árvore os pomares. (C)
   *É/São os pomares esta árvore. (I)
4. Esta árvore, ela é/são os pomares.
   Os pomares, eles é/são esta árvore.
5. ??Esta árvore é os pomares, e aquela outra também o é. (C)
   *Os pomares são esta árvore, e os laranjais também o são. (I)

Tenho muitas dúvidas aqui. Mas parece-me que a primeira é mais aceitável.

A maioria dos testes aponta para que o sujeito seja *esta árvore*, o que explicará a maior aceitabilidade de *é*. Resta a pergunta — então por que é *são* também possível, se não mesmo necessário, quando *os pomares* surge em posição pré-verbal? Uma hipótese é não estarmos perante uma inversão, não se tratando então de pares verdadeiramente equativos. É esta a hipótese que Oliveira (2001) avança em relação a pares de frases que não reagem uniformemente aos testes (pág. 118), como é aqui o caso (vejam-se os testes 4 e 5).

Indo agora ao mote da pergunta.

> O rebanho é os meus pensamentos.

ou

> A felicidade é as coisas boas.

ou ainda, pegando no exemplo de Bechara:

> Justiça é tudo, justiça é as virtudes todas.

É possível que estas frases não sejam copulativas invertidas em que anomalamente ocorre uma concordância à esquerda, mas antes predicações separadas em que o constituiente à esquerda tem um valor referencial mais forte. O exemplo de Bechara é interessante, porque *justiça* é sujeito na primeira parte (**é tudo que é a justiça*), pelo que é de esperar que a segunda tenha a mesma estrutura, com *a justiça* no papel de sujeito, argumento do predicado *as virtudes todas* e a cópula a concordar com esse sujeito.

Comment: Li isto vária vezes, mas não consigo acompanhar. Acho que compreendo até ao «tu és o professor/o professor és tu», mas a partir daí é uma desgraça. E porque é que *eu* é o sujeito em *o estado sou eu*?

Comment: @Jacinto Então? É sujeito porque se comporta como sujeito, dada a definição de sujeito que temos. A questão não é essa. O que quis mostrar foi que os dois sintagmas nominais não têm (na maioria dos casos) o mesmo comportamento, e que a concordância é feita com aquele que exibe um padrão de comportamento particular, não necessariamente com o que está no plural.

Comment: Pois, eu percebo a ideia, mas duma maneira geral não consigo compreender os testes. Parece-me que tu investiste muito tempo no estudo da gramática, e aqui escreveste para gramáticos e não para leigos como eu.

Comment: @Jacinto Não percebes a razão de ser dos testes (por quê estes e não outros) ou os testes em si (nenhum deles?)?. É que a primeira questão, mais complicada, eu não abordo (nem me parece que seja necessária para a pergunta, é preciso apenas alguma dose de fé).

Answer (score 8):

O verbo 'ser' pode concordar ora com o sujeito ora com o predicativo. Porém, na minha experiência, o falante tende a concordar com o sujeito ou com o que vem antes do verbo.
Para mim as frases em que o verbo 'ser' concorda com o predicativo soam estranhas.

Contudo, nesse caso, o mais comum no Brasil é reformular a frase. As pessoas diriam por exemplo "O pomar é composto destas cinco árvores" ou "O time é composto destes 11 jogadores", devido à ideia de que pomar e time são palavras singulares. Por oposição, a frase "A minha preocupação é os filhos" é mais comum na fala e geralmente tem uma pausa, mas em geral a frase é reformulada para que não soe estranha.

Para mais informações:
http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/verbo-ser/

Comment: Portanto, tu dirias «o pomar ***é*** estas cinco árvores» e «o time ***é*** estes onze jogadores»?

Answer (score 2):

No uso apresentado, o verbo *ser* exerce função de cópula, mas, mesmo nessa função, é necessário separar pelo menos duas situações: (i) quando o predicado é uma qualidade e, nesse caso, a cópula exerce o papel de atribuição da qualidade ao sujeito da oração; e (ii) quando o predicativo é uma entidade e, nesse caso, a cópula exerce o papel de estabelecer identidade entre o sujeito da oração e a entidade constante no predicado.

No primeiro caso, é obrigatória a concordância nominal de número entre sujeito e predicativo, logo haverá concordância verbal com ambos.  Ainda nesse caso, a troca entre sujeito e predicativo é compreendida como o uso de uma figura de linguagem, e não como a criação de uma nova oração (*e.g.*, "A lua é bonita" e "Bonita é a lua").

Contudo, no segundo caso, o sujeito e a(s) entidade(s) não têm a obrigação de concordar em número e também a troca entre o sujeito da oração original e a(s) entidade(s) presente no predicado pode ser interpretada (*e.g.*, "O Sr. Oliveira é o professor" cf. "O professor é o Sr. Oliveira").

Quando diferem os números gramaticais de sujeito e entidade(s) do predicado, essa discrepância faz soar estranho a concordância verbal somente com o sujeito da oração quando o sujeito é singular.

Em um certo sentido, é como se tivéssemos uma oração com dois sujeito com os quais sentimos necessidade de concordância verbal conjunta.  Notem que não seria um sujeito composto, pois não diríamos "O professor e o Sr. Oliveira *é* [a mesma pessoa]" como dizemos "O professor é o Senhor Oliveira".  Se ambos os sujeitos (dessa hipotética construção de sujeito duplo) forem singulares, concordamos com o singular; se ambos forem plurais, concordamos com o plural; mas quando um é singular e o outro plural (pouco importando quem é oficialmente o sujeito da oração), tendemos a concordar com o plural.

*Caveat emptor*: não tive tempo de buscar referência bibliográfica para embasar a análise acima.  Assim, *feci quod potui, faciant meliora potentes*.

Comment: <lampshading mode on>
Não, as citações latinas não são uma tentativa de soar erudição. <lampshading mode off>   =D

Comment: +1, mas se a questão é falta de tempo, podes sempre voltar mais tarde e completar ;). Isto corresponde à minha intuição.

Comment: @Jacinto Deveras.  Mas algo me diz que isso levará alguns dias...  

Comment: Eu sou paciente