# "São a manifestação" está correto nessa frase?

Tags: número-gramatical, concordância

Hoje vi uma frase supostamente dita por Bert Hellinger que me parece um pouco estranha, porém alguns amigos meus dizem que está correta:

> "As doenças de nosso corpo e mente são a manifestação que busca nos dizer que algo está em desordem" - *Bert Hellinger*

No trecho **"são a manifestação"** eu entendo que "são" está concordando com "As doenças", porém o substantivo **"manifestação"** está no singular, uma vez que estranhamente não apareceu como "manifestações".

Este não seria o correto?

> "As doenças de nosso corpo e mente são *as manifestações* que *buscam* nos dizer que algo está em desordem" - *Bert Hellinger*

---

**Edit:**

**1º)** Primeiro ponto de vista da frase:

Quem se manifesta? *A Doença.*

Logo, *"As doenças se manifestam"*.

Então, *"As doenças de nosso corpo e mente são as manifestações..."*, pois *"uma doença se manifesta"*, *"duas doenças se manifestam"*, se existem *doenças* então existem *manifestações*.

**2º)** Contrariando, ao tentar converter (ou inverter?) o sujeito da frase, chegaríamos a:

> "A manifestação que busca nos dizer que algo está em desordem são as doenças de nosso corpo e mente."

Pois a manifestação neste caso é claramente uma entidade e as doenças são o que compõem essa entidade.

*Obs.: Esses são meus pontos de vista.*

Comment: Agora eu fiquei na dúvida pois penso que possa haver dupla concordância com elementos da frase. No primeiro caso, pode se referir em gênero e número e no segundo, é para concordar com toda a frase. Espero que seja isto. Para mim, não me faz grande diferença.

Comment: Também imagino que há uma ambiguidade, mas só quis ser um pouco mais específico e descobrir de onde ela vem.

Comment: Acho que na verdade, todas as duas formas estão certas. Vos confesso uma coisa: sei que o que vou falar aqui não tem nada a ver com a questão, mas penso que o AO de 1990 causou muitas inseguranças ortográficas, pois me lembro que quando era mais novo, ou criança sabia de um monte de coisas do Português, mesmo sendo brasileiro e não me sentia tão inseguro assim na hora de escrever e ainda não havia essa história de ficar mexendo aqui e ali. Ou sou eu que fiquei velho mesmo, depois de 34 anos.

Comment: "As cores nada mais são do que a manifestação da nossa percepção de frequências eletromagnéticas", se a reduzíssimos teríamos "As cores são a manifestação da nossa percepção...". Ou "As feridas são o resultado das manifestações virais", reduzindo: "As ferias são as manifestações...". Parece que todas são possíveis, depende do que está sendo omitido na frase, provavelmente estará no contexto. [as afirmações são arbitrárias, as criei sem compromisso em declarar verdades científicas]

Comment: Não sei se esta pergunta sobre [o pomar são estas cinco árvores](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/concord%C3%A2ncia-em-n%C3%BAmero-com-o-verbo-ser-o-pomar-%C3%A9-cinco-%C3%A1rvores-ou-o-pomar-s%C3%A3) ajuda? O verbo *ser* pode ligar um singular com um plural, como nos exemplos do @Luciano. Ou ainda, "eu estava perdido no mato, e eles acharam-me: **eles foram a minha salvação**"--claramente há uma só salvação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, “as doenças […] são a manifestação” está correto: a frase é gramatical e faz sentido.

### Questão gramatical

Do ponto de vista estritamente gramatical, “as doenças […] são a manifestação” não apresenta qualquer problema. O verbo *ser* pode ligar um sujeito e um predicativo de números gramaticais diferentes, como se pode ver pelos seguintes exemplos que não levantam qualquer dúvida:

> **Vocês** foram **a minha salvação**.
>
> **Eles** são **gente** boa.
>
> **Os brasileiros** são **um povo** otimista.
>
> **A maior riqueza** do mundo são **as crianças**.

[Este artigo no Civerdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-concordancia-do-verbo-ser-com-o-predicativo-do-sujeito/34276) apresenta vários outros exemplos avalizados por gramáticos consagrados. A questão que se põe neste tipo de frases é se o verbo deve ir para o singular ou para o plural. O Gramático Evanildo Bechara, citado [nesta resposta do Artefacto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/concord%C3%A2ncia-em-n%C3%BAmero-com-o-verbo-ser-o-pomar-%C3%A9-cinco-%C3%A1rvores-ou-o-pomar-s%C3%A3/3344#3344), observa que normalmente vai para o plural. Mas nem sempre tem de ser assim, como em “migalhas é pão” [(artigo do Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-concordancia-do-verbo-ser-com-o-predicativo-do-sujeito/34276) ou “justiça é as virtudes todas” [(Bechara, resposta do Artefacto)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/concord%C3%A2ncia-em-n%C3%BAmero-com-o-verbo-ser-o-pomar-%C3%A9-cinco-%C3%A1rvores-ou-o-pomar-s%C3%A3/3344#3344).

### Questão de sentido

Agora, “as doenças […] são a manifestação” é gramatical, mas “as doenças […] são (as) manifestações” também é. A escolha entre uma e outra alternativa depende do que se quer enfatizar. Compara:

> (a) As doenças são **a principal causa** de morte em Portugal.
>
> (b) As doenças do aparelho circulatório e os tumores malignos são **as principais causas** de morte em Portugal.

Cada doença é uma causa de morte diferente, mas em (a) eu não estou interessado nessas diferenças e apresento as doenças coletivamente como a principal causa. Já em (b) eu quero destacar que cada um daqueles dois grupos de doença é individualmente uma principal causa de morte.

Do mesmo modo, em

> As doenças de nosso corpo e mente são a manifestação que busca nos dizer que algo está em desordem

o autor não está interessado em distinguir doenças ou as diferentes coisas que poderão estar em desordem, mas quer simplesmente dizer que qualquer doença é manifestação.

Answer (score 3):

A primeira opção certamente está correta, **principalmente em se tratando de textos médicos.**

> - "As doenças de nosso corpo e mente **são a manifestação** que busca nos dizer que algo está em desordem."

Na frase acima, a "manifestação " é um conjunto, e fica melhor no singular.

**Do Google Books**

> - "Placas policíclicas anelares **são a manifestação** mais comum do Lupus Eritematoso Sistêmico."
> - "Todos eles **são o manancial** da exposição sistemática ou teórica da tradição mística cristã."
> - "os sintomas negativos, **representam a manifestação** essencial da doença esquizofrênica."
> - "Clinicamente, estes tumores **representam a manifestação local** de uma doença sistêmica."
> - "Os contratos **representam a manifestação** da vontade dos indivíduos com o fim de..."
> - " As reações pessimistas de Joe **são a manifestação** natural de.."
> - "As pessoas com sintomas sem explicação médica têm mais chances de considerar que as queixas físicas **são a manifestação** de uma doença.."

A segunda opção, soa melhor aos meus ouvidos se omitirmos o artigo

> - "As doenças de nosso corpo e mente **são manifestações** que buscam nos dizer que algo está em desordem"