# Como posso identificar a posição do sujeito em uma frase com verbo de ligação?

Tags: sintaxe, sujeito

Ex..: O responsável sou eu.
         O melhor é que estejamos preparados.

Como se sabe que na posição tipica de um predicativo esta o sujeito ou o contrario?

Comment: vê os testes em https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3344/249 . Mas atenção que há frases que não respondem uniformemente aos testes. Vê as referências na resposta para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Não é tão simples ou talvez seja. Porém, muitos exemplos estão invertidos, mas a gramática tradicional foi incapaz de entender.
Na frase “Tudo são margaridas”. A posição poderá fazer-nos pensar que o sujeito é “tudo”, mas na verdade houve uma antecipação do nome predicativo. A concordância informa-nos que o sujeito é “margaridas” e que a ordem deveria ser “Margaridas são tudo”. Vejamos outra  frase “Se não percebe o perigo, o perigo é você” Logicamente, o sujeito é “você”. “Você é o perigo”. 
Dito isso, para identificar a posição do sujeito em uma frase com verbo de ligação, basta fazer uma analise mais apurada e fazer algumas inversões de termos tal como nos exemplos mencionados.
[enter link description here](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/)
[enter link description here](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf54.php)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

A ideia básica para se encontrar o sujeito é sempre perguntar à oração. Neste caso você tem duas orações.
1ª frase - Quem é o responsável? Este pratica a ação e assim é o sujeito (eu)

2ª frase - É melhor que quem esteja preparado? nesta segunda o sujeito esta oculto (nós)

Comment: O sujeito de "quem esteja preparado" é "quem". Que, dependendo do contexto, pode ser "nós", "eles", "a turma da Rua Maria" ou "o Exército iraquiano". Mas o sujeito de "É melhor que quem esteja preparado" é um sujeito oracional, "quem esteja preparado".