# Dúvida sobre silepse nesta frase

Tags: figuras-de-linguagem

Pode-se dizer que na frase **quem faz sou eu** ocorre uma silepse no sentido de que o verbo *ser*, devendo concordar com o sujeito *quem faz*, acaba concordando com o termo *eu*?

Como são classificados os termos dessa frase?

Comment: Deixarei a resposta para alguém mais experiente, mas vai uma observação: A dificuldade com o verbo *ser* é que, nem sempre, ele concorda com o sujeito, por exemplo: O que SÃO seis meses?

Comment: Boa observação. Gostaria de perguntar, por que o verbo _ser_ pode não concordar com o sujeito? Como chamamos esse fenômeno?

Comment: O verbo *ser* pode concordar com o sujeito, por exemplo: *Nós somos estudiosos*, *Ela é estudiosa*. Porém há algumas exceções, em alguns casos o verbo irá concordar com o predicativo do sujeito, por exemplo: *A maioria são estudiosos*.

Comment: Não concordo que o sujeito seja "quem faz". A minha leitura é que o sujeito é "eu"; o sujeito seria "quem faz" na frase «quem faz greve ganha o meu respeito», mas não em «quem faz [greve] sou eu».

Comment: Vê esta pergunta: ["o pomar é cinco árvores" ou "o pomar são cinco árvores"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/concord%C3%A2ncia-em-n%C3%BAmero-com-o-verbo-ser-o-pomar-%C3%A9-cinco-%C3%A1rvores-ou-o-pomar-s%C3%A3). Talvez responda à tua pergunta.

Comment: Já dizia Machado de Assis: "minha cama é palhas".