# É correto dizer "sê-lo" ao invés de "ser ele"?

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos

Considerando a seguinte frase:

*"Vi um homem de cabelos cacheados na rua. Me lembrou João. Poderia até **ser ele**, mas não era."*

No caso de trocar a expressão "ser ele" a fim de utilizar pronome oblíquo, como seria a maneira correta?

"Poderia **sê-lo**" estaria correto?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu partilho a intuição e incerteza do Artefacto, mas vou apresentar outro aspeto da questão. Repara neste exemplo diferente:

> (a) Vi ao longe um homem da tua estatura. Até **poderias ser tu**.

Esta frase é absolutamente normal, e *tu* é indubitavelmente o sujeito, porque concorda com *poderias*. O predicativo do sujeito está omisso. A frase completa seria  “poderias ser tu o tal homem” = “tu poderias ser o tal homem”. Então do mesmo modo, na tua frase,

> (b) Vi um homem de cabelos cacheados. Me lembrou João. Até **poderia ser ele**

“Até poderia ser ele” está absolutamente correto, e *ele* pode ser interpretado como sujeito de *poderia ser* (tal como *tu* na minha frase), com o predicativo também omisso: “poderia ser ele [João] o tal homem” = “ele [João] poderia ser o tal homem”. Sendo *ele* o sujeito, não pode ser substituído por *o/lo*.

Agora a questão é se na tua frase *ele* pode também ser o predicativo, estando o sujeito omisso. Neste caso a frase seria “[o tal homem] poderia ser ele [João]”, sendo *o tal homem* sujeito, caso em que seria em princípio possível (mas não necessário) substituir *ser ele* por *sê-lo*. O Artefacto analisou esta questão, e eu não me vou meter nela.

Há uma outra possibilidade, mas não me parece nada natural, que é interpretar a tua frase como “[João] até poderia ser ele [o tal homem]”. Ou seja, admitiríamos que o sujeito de *poderia ser* é o João mas está omisso e que *ele* é o predicativo e se refere a “o tal homem”. Nesse caso poderias em princípio dizer  *poderia sê-lo*, ou seja, “[João] poderia sê-lo [o tal homem]” (seria como dizer na minha frase, “poderias sê-lo [o tal homem]”). Mas isto não me parece nada natural, porque eu instintivamente interpreto *ele* como referindo o João.

Comment: Perfeito, Jacinto, muito obrigado! Agora fez ainda mais sentido. O pronome oblíquo não pode se referir ao mesmo sujeito da frase. Nesse caso, essa frase pode ter dois sujeitos, o que nos leva a essa dubiedade, mas, por citar "João" anteriormente, nos dá a impressão de que ele também é sujeito na segunda frase, o que a tornaria incorreta.

Comment: @Lucas, noutros casos poderia: em "João vestiu-se", *se* refere-se ao sujeito *João*. Mas em "X é Y", um é sujeito e o outro é predicativo. Portanto em "poderia ser ele", *ele* ou é sujeito (com predicativo omisso) ou é predicativo (com sujeito omisso). Interpretando *ele* como sujeito, fica perfeito. "Até poderia sê-lo", naquele contexto, é que é duvidoso. Mesmo que seja correto, é estranho. Eu tenho visto *o* como predicativo é em frases como "João gostaria de ser médico. Até poderia sê-lo, se se empenhasse", "João pensa que é esperto. Poderá sê-lo, mas neste caso está enganado" >>

Comment: Ou seja, o demonstrativo *o* normalmente refere-se a um atributo (médico, esperto), não a uma pessoa. É claro, isto pode ser simplesmente por frases do tipo "João é [atributo X]" serem mais comuns que "João pode ser [pessoa X]".

Comment: ser rico, ser pobre, ser + ajetivo= sê-lo, substitui ao ajetivo//ser aquele homen, ser aquela pessoa, ser + substantivo: ser ele ou ser ela. Me parece óbvio....

Comment: @Lambie não me parece nada óbvio. Ser vilão/um vilão/o melhor pai do mundo e outros grupos nominais parecem-me em maior ou menor medida substituíveis por -o (e.g. _O João pensa que é o melhor pai do mundo, mas não o é_).

Comment: Se ver comparando com o español: Pueder **serlo** [bonito, feo, simpático]. Puede **ser él** [el hombre, el criminoso, el burrito]. João puede ser el mejor padre del mundo=puede **serlo** =João pode ser o melhor pai do mundo= João pode sê-lo. O serlo (sê-lo) iría com o predicado inteiro: ser o melhor pai do mundo. Só pode ser sê-lo, pronome: o com l por causa do ser. Ou seja: oblíquo átono.

Answer (score 3):

Intuitivamente, diria imediatamente que não. Mas vejamos.

Numa frase equativa (duas expressões nominais ligadas pelo verbo ser), só o predicado pode ser substituído pelo clítico invariável. Nem sempre é fácil identificar o sujeito e o predicado, e por vezes as duas expressões nominais têm o mesmo valor referencial, mas, neste caso, parece-me que *ele* é o sujeito da frase. Aplicando [um dos testes](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/concord%c3%a2ncia-em-n%c3%bamero-com-o-verbo-ser-o-pomar-%c3%a9-cinco-%c3%a1rvores-ou-o-pomar-s%c3%a3/3344#3344), o do foco, e simplificando um pouco a frase, temos:

> O homem que viste é o João ou o amigo?
> O homem que vi é O JOÃO.
> O JOÃO é o homem que vi.
>
> O João é o homem ou a criança que viste?
> *O HOMEM QUE VI é o João.
> O João é o HOMEM QUE VI.

Isto sugere que a frase canónica é *o João é o homem que vi*, e que *o João* é o sujeito.

Portanto, assumindo que o par se comporta da forma típica, podemos dizer:

> O homem que vi, o João poderia **sê-lo**.

mas não:

> *O João, o homem que vi poderia **sê-lo**.

A minha intuição diz-me que a última frase é de facto inaceitável, mas também não estou 100% confortável com a anterior (*o João poderia ser ele* parece-me melhor).

Comment: Muito obrigado, Artefacto! De fato essa frase tem me deixado confuso. Ela também não me soa correta. Talvez, nesse caso, fosse mais adequado esconder o sujeito: "Poderia até ser, mas não era." já que na frase anterior eu cito "João". O que acha?